# HTTP Status 500 - org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/SuperAdmin/header.jsp at line 125

Tags: java, spring, jsp

In my spring project i want to redirect to login page is user is not redirect, i am new to spring and i did not use spring security therefor i used response.sendRedirect() function for redirection but it is not working my code as below.

```
<%
if (session.getAttribute("userRole")!= "Admin")
{
  response.sendRedirect("/login.html");

}
%>
```

in header but i got error
HTTP Status 500 - org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/SuperAdmin/header.jsp at line 125

in line no 125 i have another condition for side bar

```
    <%  
     if (session.getAttribute("new_school_id")==null)
     { 
    %>
    <jsp:include page="sidebar_new.jsp" />
   <% 
    }else{ %>
    <jsp:include page="sidebar.jsp" />
    <% }%>
```

Comment: you have to add `jstl.jar` and `stardard.jar` to your build path.

Comment: I have added but it not working.

Comment: Could you post full stacktrace?

Comment: <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
include it .

Comment: what is the folder structure for keeping jsp in your project? I mean where are these sidebar_new.jsp and sidebar.jsp.

Comment: I have added already <%@ taglib uri="java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"; prefix="c" %>